# MSChart changing my value

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

I have an MS Chart.
My code is the following:

```
chart.Series[chartType].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, xCaption, yValues, yCaption);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "CustomAxisXFormat";
chart.FormatNumber += new EventHandler<FormatNumberEventArgs>(chart_FormatNumber);
```

Then

```
private void chart_FormatNumber(object sender, FormatNumberEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ElementType == ChartElementType.AxisLabels &&
        e.Format == "CustomAxisXFormat")
    {
        e.LocalizedValue = string.Format("{0:hh tt}", new DateTime(1, 1, 2, (int)e.Value, 0, 0).AddHours(-1));
    }
}
```

`xValues` and `yValues` are are arrays of ints.
The problem I am having is, if `xValues = int[]{1,2,3}`, when `chart_FormatNumber` handles the event, the values (`e.Value`) change to `{2,3,4}`.
So have to do a subtraction there to make it the correct value.
Can somebody tell me what is going on and/or how to stop MSChart from changing my values?

Comment: I tested it, and it works fine on my machine. In fact, if I remove the subctraction the labels are correctly shown. You should post a small but complete example to reproduce the issue (if it's too long for a single post, use http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Thanks for attempting to reproduce this.  I was able to find the cause the my issue.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some head scratching, I figured out what was happening.  I was supplying my x parameters are int.  MS chart was adding +1 and -1 to the x axis range.  The x values I was providing was `xValues = int[]{1,2,3}`.  In `chart_FormatNumber()` I was getting `{0,1,2,3,4}` which was throwing me off.